# How to remove underline from font awesome icon

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im using a font awesome icon in my react app but for some reason it isnt displayed correctly

Here is my code:

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <div class="top float-right" >
     <a href="https://t.me/memecoins">
      <i class="fab fa-telegram fa-2x" ></i></a>
      </div>
      <a href="../"><img className="logo float-left " src={logo} alt="Logo"/></a>
      </div>
```

and thats css

```
.fab{
  background-color:#263238;

}
```

and my font awesome icon looks on my screen like this:
[image]

When i have the font-awesome icon on 3x and larger i dont see this underline, its not there anymore it only shows at small icon size

I fixed the code to this:

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
     <a href="https://t.me/memecoins" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-telegram fa-3x float-right" ></i></a>
      <a href="../"><img className="logo float-left " src={logo} alt="Logo"/></a>
      <h1 className="text-center text-warning mt-3 mb-4">MEMECO.IN</h1>
      <h5 className="text-center text-success mb-4">
        <a href="https://boards.4channel.org/biz/catalog" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" >/biz/ </a>
      Coin Tracker</h5>
    </div>
  );
};
```

removing the div did the trick

Answer (score 4):

The reason of underline is `a` tag not related to Font-awesome, so you have to remove `decoration` from `a` tag in CSS.

**For example:**

```
<a href="https://t.me/memecoins" style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}> 
      <i class="fab fa-telegram fa-2x" ></i></a>
```

Or in your CSS file:

```
a {
   text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: @yappytwan 
Can you attach your code after the edit ? 
I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
<a class="hr" href="https://t.me/memecoins">
      <i class="fab fa-telegram fa-2x" ></i>
</a>
```

Style:

```
.hr {
      text-decoration:none;
}

.fab{
  background-color:#263238;
}
```

Setting the text-decoration to `none` will remove the underline from the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Maybe then your `div` class styles do something strange. Can you write them above? (As much more information you can please)...
Maybe you should totally remove that part `class="top float-right"` first and see what it does.

Comment: ok it worked i removed the whole div and the underline is gone- thanks

Comment: Your welcome. Just keep in mind that when you use `a` tags you need to use `text-decoration:none` to remove the underline. From that point the above answers are correct.